# Is this subset linearly independent or linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the $n$-space $\Bbb R^n$ determine whether or not the set $\{e_1-e_2,e_2-e_3, \dots, e_{n}-e_{1} \}$ is Linearly Independent.

I tried solving it using the definition of a LI set, taking $e_1, e_2$ etc to be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Finally equating it to the zero of $\Bbb R^n$, I get all the scalars $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$

So should I conclude that they are not necessarily zero and hence the given set is Linearly Dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a fair guess, but to actually prove it, you must *demonstrate* that they are not necessarily zero. It looks like what you've shown is that if $$a_1(e_1-e_2)+a_2(e_2-e_3)+\cdots+a_{n-1}(e_{n-1}-e_n)+a_n(e_n-e_1)=0,$$ then all the $a_k$ are equal. For linear dependence, we need the other direction, but we don't have to prove it for all non-zero values of $a_1=\cdots=a_n.$ A single value suffices. Try $a_k=1$ for $1\le k\le n$ and see what happens. Of course, you certainly *can* set all $a_k=a$ for some arbitrary non-zero real $a,$ but it isn't really necessary for the question at hand.

Comment: ok, suppose if we take $a_k=a\ne 0$ the equation is satisfied. this confirms that the given set is LD. Thanks !!

Comment: No problem! Incidentally, if we were dealing with the linear transformation $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ taking $e_1\mapsto e_1-e_2,$ $e_2\mapsto e_2-e_3,$ ..., $e_{n-1}\mapsto e_{n-1}-e_n,$ and $e_n\mapsto e_n-e_1,$ then your work shows that the kernel (or null space) of this transformation is precisely the set of all $\Bbb R^n$ vectors whose components are all equal. Thus, the extra work can come in handy sometimes.