# Linear independence of difference of vectors $v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,v_3-v_4,v_4-v_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose there is a set of vectors $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$. Are $v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,v_3-v_4,v_4-v_1$ linearly independent?

If $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and $v_4$ are linearly independent, then $v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,v_3-v_4,v_4-v_1$ span the same subspace and the dimension is the same. So, $v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,v_3-v_4,v_4-v_1$ are linearly independent. However, the question does not provide whether or not $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and $v_4$ are linearly independent so I'm lost.

Is this question missing a necessary condition to answer or am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of [this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478326/11619), among other things. In that case it was given that $v_i$ were linearly independent, but the answer covers this.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to visualize this in 3D. Three vectors may be linearly independent, but there is a unique 2D hyperplane going through them.  Thus when you look at their differences, they are all parallel to this hyperplane, and hence they span a 2D space (the hyperplane translated to the origin.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$(v_1-v_2)+(v_2-v_3)+(v_3-v_4)+(v_4-v_1)=0$$

therefore the given vectors are in any case linearly dependent.